# Angular - Read row value for checkbox in table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation here where I have a list of data in table. The total column is three and one of them is a checkbox. Kindly see below

[image]

this is my codes look like

```
<div nz-row>
    <nz-table nz-col nzSpan="22" [nzLoading]="loading"
              nzTitle="Assign a new role to the group" [nzData]="moduledata">
      <thead nzSingleSort>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th nzShowSort nzSortKey="module">Module</th>
            <th nzShowFilter [nzFilters]="filterrole"
                (nzFilterChange)="updateFilter($event)">Role</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let module of moduledata">
          <td nzShowCheckbox name='tableCheck' id='tableCheck'></td>
          <td>{{module.module}}</td>
          <td>{{module.role}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
  </div>
```

Below is the expected result to be send to the backend when i click submit button

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciate. For you guys information, I still haven't done any logic in the .ts file yet.

Comment: What's your actual **question**?  All you posted was some code and a statement about not actually trying to solve whatever problem it is you didn't tell us about.

Comment: @Claies I have clearly mention in the title of my question. "Read row value".. so anyway, im trying to read the entire row value when the user click the checkbox of that row. thank you.

Comment: “Read row value” isn’t a **question**, and clearly you are trying to get someone to write your code for you, which isn’t what this site is about.

Comment: @Claies im not hoping someone write the code.. just some reference to the other tutorial. or maybe you have some similar example in your project. I'll try on my own after that. it just i dont have any idea on how to proceed. It the same like the below guys answer. he just gave me some clue on how to do. and i manage to solve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the official example of what you're trying to do:
https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/table/demo/row-selection.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-table-row-selection',
  template: `
    <nz-table
      #rowSelectionTable
      [nzData]="data"
      (nzCurrentPageDataChange)="currentPageDataChange($event)"
      (nzPageIndexChange)="refreshStatus()"
      (nzPageSizeChange)="refreshStatus()">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th nzShowCheckbox [(nzChecked)]="allChecked" [nzIndeterminate]="indeterminate" (nzCheckedChange)="checkAll($event)"></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of rowSelectionTable.data">
          <td nzShowCheckbox [(nzChecked)]="data.checked" [nzDisabled]="data.disabled" (nzCheckedChange)="refreshStatus()"></td>
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.age}}</td>
          <td>{{data.address}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>`,
  styles  : []
})
export class NzDemoTableRowSelectionComponent {
  allChecked = false;
  indeterminate = false;
  displayData = [];
  data = [
    {
      name    : 'John Brown',
      age     : 32,
      address : 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
      checked : false,
      disabled: false
    },
    {
      name    : 'Jim Green',
      age     : 42,
      address : 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
      checked : false,
      disabled: false
    },
    {
      name    : 'Joe Black',
      age     : 32,
      address : 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
      checked : false,
      disabled: false
    },
    {
      name    : 'Disabled User',
      age     : 32,
      address : 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
      checked : false,
      disabled: true
    }
  ];

  currentPageDataChange($event: Array<{ name: string; age: number; address: string; checked: boolean; disabled: boolean; }>): void {
    this.displayData = $event;
    this.refreshStatus();
  }

  refreshStatus(): void {
    const allChecked = this.displayData.filter(value => !value.disabled).every(value => value.checked === true);
    const allUnChecked = this.displayData.filter(value => !value.disabled).every(value => !value.checked);
    this.allChecked = allChecked;
    this.indeterminate = (!allChecked) && (!allUnChecked);
  }

  checkAll(value: boolean): void {
    this.displayData.forEach(data => {
      if (!data.disabled) {
        data.checked = value;
      }
    });
    this.refreshStatus();
  }
}
```

Comment: hi there.. thank you for the reply.. however for my data. i dont have any checked field. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: i simply add the new checked:boolean to the my listdata.. and i manage to use the data.checked value in the during the onsubmit () method that i create.. thanks